# Are there disadvantages/consequences to adding scheduled tasks directly to /etc/crontab instead of using the crontab command?

Tags: cron

CentOS 5.x

I noticed that someone (presumably another admin) added an entry directly to the bottom of `/etc/crontab` so it reads like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
00 3 * * 0 root foocommand
```

Assuming that I indeed want the command to run as root, are there consequences to adding scheduled tasks this way?  I'm more accustomed to using `crontab -e` to add/edit scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From running the command in the crontab file there is no difference. At least Vixie cron (as on CentOS) checks every minute if the spool directory's modification time or that of `/etc/crontab` has changed.

However if you edit via `crontab -e`, and write the crontab will be checked for glaring errors. E.g if the last line of your crontab is `* * * *` you will get the message:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.HbT2Sa/crontab":27: bad day-of-week
errors in crontab file, can't install
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)
```

(at least if that last line is line 27).

Such a checking mechanism is of course not in place if you just add lines to the `crontab` file (either `/etc/crontab` or those in `/var/spool/cron/`).

Comment: Sorry - I'm still a bit confused.  Why is the format different between `/var/spool/cron/foo` and `/etc/crontab`.  Are two completely different cron tools involved?

Comment: @MikeB `/etc/crontab` is executed by root, and you need to specify a username as who you run the command (6th field). The others are user crontabs, they always run as the user the crontab belongs to, and don't need that field (it's implicit).